# Next.js how to add secure API communication

Tags: javascript, api, axios, next.js

I am creating a simple form to subscribe to the MailerLite newsletter with React and Next.js.
I am using this API: https://github.com/zygos/mailerlite-api-v2-node

I see that it is safe to add the API key to a .env file, as described [here](https://dev.to/thepuskar/how-to-hide-your-api-keys-in-react-4k55).

Here is a sample of the code I have:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
const MailerLite = require("mailerlite-api-v2-node").default;

const mailerLite = MailerLite("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

  const getTheSubscriberId = (newSubEmail) => {
    mailerLite
      .getSubscribers()
      .then((subList) => {
[..........]
 return (
[..........]
  <form className="newsletter-form" onSubmit={_handleSubmit}>
          <input
            type="email"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="your mail address"
            name="EMAIL"
            required={true}
            value={email}
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          />

[..........]
```

I am concerned with Security. I do not want other people to see my API key.
The above usage is a bad one. I can't run it on a component, because the API key is visible in the browsers.

Is it possible to still keep using that library, or I need to do something as eplained [here](https://leerob.io/blog/mailchimp-next-js)?

I wanted to use a server.js, but Netlify, Vercel etc do not accept "never ending processes".

Thus I am looking for other solutions that will help me hide the API key. Please suggest what I can do in this case.

1. Is it possible to run such app without a server?
2. Can I use that [library](https://github.com/zygos/mailerlite-api-v2-node) in a way the API will be hidden?
3. If it is possible, can you please help me to understand how I can achieve that?

Comment: The client is never secure. No matter what you do, if the key is available to the browser, it's available to the public. I'm not sure that you need an ongoing process. If you have a handful of emails to send, it can be done while the form response is being generated. If have more than that, you should be using a service designed for sending mass emails. Either way, an ongoing process isn't required.

Comment: Yes, this is why I am asking here what to do in order to prevent it. Maybe it is possible to somehow achieve it in Node.js, so that the request will be sent by the server, not by the browser.

Comment: From the name of the library itself it looks like it was intended to be used by Node.js instead of the browser. By coincidence it works in the browser because axios also works in the browser. Just create a node backend and send the form data to that backend without exposing any API keys. Then have that backend actually call the library functions with the API keys safely stored in the server

Comment: Thank you. It makes sense. Is there any tutorial I can follow in order to achieve it? I have no idea how to make such communication